# Sugar ORM blocking UI Thread on init

Tags: android, multithreading, performance, orm, sugarorm

I'm using Sugar ORM in Version 1.3.1 for my android 5.1 app.

Today, i noticed after installing my app that Sugar ORM is blocking the UI Thread for initialization for about 2.4 seconds.

Is there a way to get this stuff done in a background thread to improve the UX?

```
04-07 20:14:42.179  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ on create
04-07 20:14:44.354  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.358  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.358  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.360  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.362  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.365  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.366  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.368  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.370  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.372  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.373  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.375  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.377  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.378  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.380  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.381  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.383  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.385  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.389  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.390  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.392  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.395  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.397  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.399  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.400  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.402  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.402  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.405  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.406  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.407  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.407  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.408  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.409  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.410  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.411  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.412  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.413  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.414  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.415  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.415  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.416  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.417  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.418  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.418  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.420  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.420  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.420  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.421  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.421  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.422  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.422  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.423  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.423  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.424  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.425  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.426  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.427  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.427  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.429  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.429  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.430  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.431  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.431  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.432  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.432  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ domain class
04-07 20:14:44.506  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ create table
04-07 20:14:44.506  10407-10407/com.sample.app D/Sugar﹕ Fetching properties
04-07 20:14:44.507  10407-10407/com.sample.app I/Sugar﹕ creating table ARTICLE
```

Comment: It seems to be a feature: https://github.com/satyan/sugar/issues/269#issuecomment-90805581. Any workaround is welcome...

Comment: No workaround, no bug-fixing -> i switched to ActiveAndroid: https://github.com/pardom/ActiveAndroid

Answer (score 5):

As you suggest doing the data base initialization in a background task is the simplest solution that comes to my mind.
At first, I guess you noticed that the sugar creation starts for the first time just when you use an object that extends the SugarRecord. So what I do is pull this action in the very beginning of my app launch (in the background of course). And this is how I do it:

1. First I've defined an object just like this:

   ```
    public class DBInit extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            Offer.last(Offer.class);
            return null;
        }
    }
   ```

   Where Offer is a custom object of mine that extends SugarRecord. That is, by performing a dummy search I trigger the DB creation.
2. I launch this task as soon as possible in the app initialization. For instance in the onCreate, just like this:

   ```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        // Init the data base in a AsyncTask
        DBInit dbInit = new DBInit();
        dbInit.execute();
    }
   ```

I hope you find this workaround useful enough.

EDIT: If you use a version without .last() method you may achieve the same by doing `Offer.listAll(Offer.class)` instead of `Offer.last(Offer.class)`. However, I would avoid that because you could end up pulling over hundred or thousands objects you have stored in there. So what I do in my projects is to define an abstract class and make my objects inherit from this and not from SugarRecord, let's see it:

```
public abstract class BaseSugarRecord extends SugarRecord{

    public static <T extends SugarRecord> T checkFor(Class<T> type, final String _id, int id){
        List<T> found = find(type, _id+" = ?", String.valueOf(id));
        return !found.isEmpty() ? found.get(0) : null;
    }

    public static <T extends SugarRecord> List<T> listAll(Class<T> type, final String _id, int id){
       return find(type, _id+" = ?", String.valueOf(id));
    }
}
```

The parameter `final String _id` must be the serialized name of the variable used to perform the search. It is recommended to define it inside your custom class as you'll see below. Also the `int id` is the value of such variable, in this case, a custom ID.

Using this custom class that extends SugarOrm allow me to overload the `.listAll` method as well as include custom ones. Furthermore, what I'm looking for is to perform a search into the DB that doesn't return a single object in order to save memory consumption. And I do that, then, by changing the function inside doInBackground defined before:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    Offer.checkFor(Offer.class,Offer.ID_OFFER, 0);
    return null;
}
```

Here I put an extract of how I make my custom objects to inherit from this abstract class:

```
public class Offer extends BaseSugarRecord {

    public final static String ID_OFFER = "id_offer";
    @SerializedName(ID_OFFER)
    private int idOffer;
    // ...
```

Comment: `.last` API is not available. I'm using sugar 1.3

Comment: @AdiyatMubarak: What he means is to use any method to trigger the SugarORM. Preferably do not use listAll(), as it may prove to be a heavy operation.